# I have a Ruby script that takes 40 mins to run, how do I integrate this into a Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby script that crawls a site, and takes 40 minutes. What I would like to do is dump the results into a database and be able to do regular `ActiveRecord` stuff on the data.

1. If I put it in a Rails app and have a 'start' button that initiates the script, will it time out?
2. Ideally I want the script to run at least once a day - and update the db - so would my best bet be to create a rake task, or is there some other way to do this?
3. If I am wrapping this in a Rails App, in which folder should I put the script and what is the best way to approach it? I can't drop it in a model file - because that doesn't make any sense.
4. I have never done any 'Job' type processing before, but this sounds like it may fall in that purview. What other things should I consider when doing this?

Edit 1:

Another question is, if I put this particular Ruby script in my `/lib` directory, how do I get it to interact with the DB? I usually interact with the DB from the model and controller. How would I store the results in my DB after it is run?

Comment: http://phrogz.net/drb-server-for-long-running-web-processes

Comment: possible duplicate of [A cron job for rails: best practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices)

Comment: I like using Rails' built-in `script/runner` for this. It's made to run non-Rails code with full access to the Rails models and environment, but not as part of the MVC. Its very convenient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to give you some straightforward answers.

A) You would most likely put it as a background job. There are some decent gems for that. Consider https://github.com/defunkt/resque or something more lightweight such as https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job.

B) A rake task would suffice and then run it with either of the mentioned libraries. Another option would be a cron job.

C) You should put it in the lib/ directory.

D) You should always have some kind of processing log available in order to track potential errors. Be sure to read the instructions properly if you choose any of the two libraries mentioned above.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Thank you very much. More or less covers everything I want to know.

Comment: I guess another question is....given that I am running this task as a background job, how will I update the db? As in, normally in a Rails App a model is what interacts with the db. How would I do that here?

Comment: This is a bit more complicated. I would probably have a model which represent whatever you are crawling from the website. Then extend your existing script with the functionality to create database records. This shouldn't be as hard as it might seem. You will have access to your classes even from within the lib/ directory.

Comment: So should I let the script inherit from this model that I create? Then when I get the results back, I just add them to the db like I would any ActiveRecord model? Or should I create a new class in my `/lib` file and force AR to work with my script alone?

Comment: I would keep a model inside model/ directory which represent your data. The model should inherit from ActiveRecord or similar ORM. In your script inside your lib/ directory you can then call your model by doing YourModel.create(data) in which data is a hash of key value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to set up the job as a rake task. Then test the rake task from the command line to ensure that it works.

Finally, add the rake task as a cronjob on your server and have yourself emailed the resulting log.

For my app, I have a "Nightly" rake task that handles several sub-tasks. It does various clean-up tasks, runs the nightly reports etc.

**A job processing system** such as Delay Job would probably be overkill for a once-a-day type task. My app also uses delay job, but for many many client initiated tasks throughout the day.

Remember that you also need a process to watch the delay job process (and re-start it if necessary). I use [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), there are other alternatives too.

Comment: Will delay_job give me a log of the task run? Or is that something custom I have to build?

Comment: I also updated the question with another part I am curious about.

Answer (score 1):

Use [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to do cron jobs.

Comment: whenever allows you to schedule task by writing ruby. It will convert this into crontab syntax. It will run gracefully just like any other scripts. Check my answer on another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816934/how-to-run-sunspot-reindex-in-background-for-every-four-hours/10818572#10818572.